How can I get MacOS Sonoma to recognize the scanner in my Canon imageClass MF4880dw all-in-one device?
My new MacBook Pro running MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1  works with the printer in my Canon ImageCLASS MF4880dw all-in-one printer/scanner/fax, but I can't get it to recognize the scanner. The drivers for both the printer and the scanner at Canon's web site list MacOS 14.4.1 as a valid OS, and, as I said, the printer works fine.
When I use the Canon MF Scan Utility to try to add the scanner via IP address and I enter the IP address shown by the MF4880dw, I'm told "The specified scanner is not supported." This seems contradictory to the information for the scanner driver at Canon's web site, which lists 14.4.1 as an OS where the driver can be used.
The support page for the MF4880dw says that support is no longer available, and my request for help at the Canon Community has gone unanswered. I'm hoping for better luck here...
